# Write strings in a file in between already existing strings in the same file

Tags: node.js, fs

So theres a file which i can fill with strings using fs.write(), however I want to basically edit that file, specifically add strings to the file at specific positions in between already existing strings. I've tried many things listed on nodejs documentation about fs but I was never getting my desired result. Please help.

fs.createWriteStream but I am not able to figure out the options part of start here.

Comment: Basically  you need to rewrite the file, first with the stuff before the insertion point, then your inserted data, then the rest of the original.

Comment: Actually I did that, but I was wondering if there is a simpler solution for the same, I guess not.